# A list of chess variants and their popularity

Tags: chess-variants

How many chess variant are there? (Apparently a lot.) If possible could you include the popularity of each variant and its major event. For example, I know that there's a US bughouse chess championship. The list doesn't have to be comprehensive.

Comment: All chess variants are not suitable for playing, but may be otherwise useful. For example, in problem chess - which is more of an art than game - there are some popular variants or rules, which give us pleasant compositions.

Comment: Agree. I used double chess to improve my vision

Comment: @JoriO haha including 9LX?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To simply name a few of the variants here would need a huge amount of space, because there are many. However, you have a list of variations in the Wikipedia entry:

- [Chess variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_variant).

This entry is not comprehensive, and a few variations that cannot be found there appear in the webpage:

- [Alphabetical Index of Chess variants](http://www.chessvariants.org/alphabet.html).

These sites do not come with popularity rankings, and the same way chess itself probably does not have a "major" event (one could consider the World Chess Championship to be it, but as only two players play and the number of games and funds has been so drastically reduced, I'm not sure anymore), probably there is not a single "major" event for these variants too. However, to a certain extent, the length of the Wikipedia article on a certain variation can measure its popularity, so I suggest you take a look at the Wikipedia category:

- [Category: Chess variant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Chess_variants)

Comment: Like the idea of measuring popularity using article length

Answer (score 2):

The Chess Variant Pages actually does have a couple of rankings (at least one is new since Pablo's answer):

- [Community Favorites](https://www.chessvariants.com/index/favorites.php)
- [Recognized Variants](https://www.chessvariants.com/rindex.html)
- [Most Played on Game Courier](https://www.chessvariants.com/play/pbm/listgames.php?max=50)
- [Game Ratings](https://www.chessvariants.com/index/avgratings.php)

I'd also point out that variants that can be played at other sites, like those at [lichess.org](https://lichess.org/) and [greenchess.net](https://greenchess.net/variants.php), are presumably fairly popular.